# Solving matrix equation $AX = B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I want to solve the matrix equation $AX = B$, where the matrix $A$ and $B$ are given as follows

$A = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
     0.1375 &   0.0737  &  0.1380  & 0.1169 &  0.1166 \\
    0.0926  &   0.0707   &  0.0957   &  0.0873  &   0.0733 \\
    0.0767   &   0.0642  &   0.0810    &  0.0766  &    0.0599 \\
    0.1593 &    0.1020 &    0.1636 &    0.1451   &  0.1317
  \end{bmatrix}$

$B = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
     0.2794   &   0.0065  &    0.2271    &  0.1265   &   0.2773\\
    0.1676  &  0.2365  &  0.1430  &  0.1015 &   0.0632 \\
     0.0645  &   0.2274 &    0.1009 &    0.1806 &    0.0503\\
    0.2326  &  0.1261  &  0.2867 &   0.2846  &  0.1979
  \end{bmatrix}$

Could anybody help me how to solve this problem? I need help with this.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you checked if $A$ is invertible?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan $A$ is rectangular matrix.

Comment: Good. So what have you tried? Why do you expect there to be a solution? Are these just random numbers or do they have some significance?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I had constructed an example for that I have to solve the matrix equation $A'*A*A' X = A'$. I haven't read before solving of matrix equations although I am aware of how to solve sytem of linear equation $Ax = b$.

Comment: Matlab will do it with the simple command: X = A \ B.

Comment: I would request to reopen the question since question is not off topic. I wanted to ask how to solve the system of matrix equation $AX = B$, where the unknown $X$ and $B$ both are matrices that I understood from the answers given below. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at each column of $X$. If we denote it as $X_i$ and the columns of $B$ as $B_i$ then 
your problem reduces to 5 problems
$$
A X_i = B_i
$$
In each of the problems, you have more unknowns than equations, you know you will not have a unique solution.

If you use a calculator, the *row-echelon* form will give you a parametric solution. Alternatively, you can set one of the elements of $X_i$ to zero and reduce the number of unknowns and then parametrize by this variable. Let me show you how to do it for the first column and the rest are the same

$$
\begin{pmatrix}0.1375 & 0.0737 & 0.138 & 0.1169 & 0.1166\cr 0.0926 & 0.0707 & 0.0957 & 0.0873 & 0.0733\cr 0.0767 & 0.0642 & 0.081 & 0.0766 & 0.0599\cr 0.1593 & 0.102 & 0.1636 & 0.1451 & 0.1317\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \\ x_5 \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}0.2794\cr 0.1676\cr 0.0645\cr 0.2326\end{pmatrix}
$$
Move $x_5$ to the right and side to write
$$
\begin{pmatrix}0.1375 & 0.0737 & 0.138 & 0.1169\cr 0.0926 & 0.0707 & 0.0957 & 0.0873\cr 0.0767 & 0.0642 & 0.081 & 0.0766\cr 0.1593 & 0.102 & 0.1636 & 0.1451\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4  \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-0.1166\cr -0.0733\cr -0.0599\cr -0.1317\end{pmatrix}x_5 +
\begin{pmatrix}0.2794\cr 0.1676\cr 0.0645\cr 0.2326\end{pmatrix}
$$

Solve this as you normally would. Here $x_5$ is a free variable.

*note* For this to work, you need to make sure that (a) rows are linearly independent. If not get rid of dependent rows; (b) Make sure that the columns you keep on the left are linearly independent. In this case I checked both to be true

Comment: You seem to be aware of pseudo inverse of $A$. If you know how to calculate it, then the "best" answer is $X=A ^\dagger B$ where $A^\dagger$ is the pseudo inverse of $A$. If you use Octave or Matlab, the command would be: X = \pinv(A)*B

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I got my answer. I applied the same by using matlab.

Answer (score 4):

Write $B=(b_1,\dots,b_n)$ and $X=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ with $b_i$ and $x_i$ the columns of $B$ and $X$ respectively. I assume you are able to solve $Ax=b$. Now, solve the $n$ linear equations $Ax_1=b_1$ to $Ax_n=b_n$. You can now 'glue' the $x_i$ together to get the matrix $X$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had to only one of the answers from two. :)

Answer (score 1):

A little theory: It is concerned with the [*Kronecker product*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Matrix_equations) and the *vectorization* of matrices.
The Kronecker product, denoted by $\otimes$, is an operation on two matrices of arbitrary size resulting in a block matrix. For example, $A \in R^{m \times n}, B \in R^{p \times q}$, then the Kronecker product $A \otimes B$ is the $mp \times nq$ block matrix:
$\begin{bmatrix} a_{11}B & \cdots & a_{1n}B \\ \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\ a_{m1}B & \cdots & a_{mn}B  \end{bmatrix}$.
The vectorization of a matrix $X$, denoted by $\operatorname{vec}(X)$, is formed by stacking the columns of $X$ into a single column vector. For example, if $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 & 6 \end{bmatrix}$, then $\operatorname{vec}(A) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 4 \\ 2 \\ 5 \\ 3 \\ 6 \end{bmatrix}$.
**The key point here is:**

> The Kronecker product, together with the vectorization, can be used to get a convenient representation for some matrix equations. For the matrix equation $AXB = C$, where $A, B$ and $C$ are given matrices and the matrix $X$ is the unknown. We can rewrite this equation as:
>    $(B^\top \otimes A) \operatorname{vec}(X) = \operatorname{vec}(AXB) = \operatorname{vec}(C)$. Now, we get a linear system and you can solve it in standard ways.

For your problem: $AX = B \Rightarrow AXI = B \Rightarrow \operatorname{vec}(AXI) = \operatorname{vec}(B) \Rightarrow (I^{\top} \otimes A) \operatorname{vec}(X) = \operatorname{vec}(B)$ $\Rightarrow (I \otimes A) \operatorname{vec}(X) = \operatorname{vec}(B)$. It is a linear system now.

There are also some useful theorems on Kronecker product to help you to identify when your matrix equation has a unique solution.